# Does ubuntu use 'DS' & 'SS' segments?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64, memory-segmentation

In Ubuntu 14.04 amd64, I dump the GDT info in a kernel module:

```
0000:  NULL desc
0008:  32-bit CODE desc, DPL 0
0010:  64-bit CODE desc, DPL 0
0018:  DATA desc, DPL 0
0020:  32-bit CODE desc, DPL 3
0028:  DATA desc, DPL 3
0030:  64-bit CODE desc, DPL 3
0038:  NULL desc
0040:  busy TSS desc
0050:  NULL desc
0058:  NULL desc
0060:  NULL desc
0068:  NULL desc
0070:  NULL desc
0078:  16-bit DATA desc, DPL 3
```

and also dump the segment registers for the kernel module:

```
CS = 10H
DS = 00H
ES = 00H
SS = 00H
FS = 00H
GS = 00H
```

Q1: Does kernel module not use DS and SS?

On the other side, I wrote a ring 3 application, also dump the segment registers in main():

```
CS = 33H
DS = 00H
ES = 00H
SS = 2BH
FS = 00H
GS = 00H
```

Q2: The app's CS points to 64-bit code desc in GDT, SS points to DATA desc in GDT. That's no problem, but why the app's DS is also 00H?

I don't think gcc can compile all the code without using DS or SS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

64-bit mode (aka long mode) does not use segmentation, so any null selector (i.e. `00H`) will work for data segments (all but CS). The code segment is still necessary for selecting 64-bit mode vs 32-bit (compatibility) mode, but the `offset` and `length` parts of the selector are not used.

So, in a sense, DS and SS *are* still being "used" (because it's more-or-less impossible to avoid them), but not from the GDT.

Comment: In 64 bit mode, FS and GS can still be used, with the intention of mapping for kernel or similar type memory spaces.

Comment: FS and GS are used through `MSR_FS_BASE` and `MSR_GS_BASE` for offsetting as you mentioned

Comment: In 32 bit Flat mode, segmentation is also not used, nevertheless DS (and usually ES) need to point to a valid segment descriptor or the application will be terminated immediately. Is there just some implication in 64 bit mode what 00 means?

Comment: @PMF segmentation *is* technically used in 32-bit mode (indeed, DS and ES need to point to valid descriptors), but most OS's choose not to use the offset+limit features. The difference in 64-bit mode is that the *hardware* ignores the offset+limit fields.

Comment: Also in 32 bit mode, the tables used by the segment registers can be used for PAE - [Physical Address Extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension). Although each process is limited to a 4GB address space, PAE allows an OS (mostly server versions) to support more than 4GB physical memory.

Comment: @rcgldr PAE is implemented via page tables, not segmentation.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen - brain fade on my part, as you stated, PAE is implemented via the virtual (to physical) memory page tables. The segment registers would normally just define a 32 bit virtual address space. I'm not sure if any 32 bit operating system would do anything special with segment registers FS and GS, to split up the virtual address space between application and kernel.

Comment: @rcgldr typically 32-bit Windows uses FS for the [thread information block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block). I don't think it uses GS.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen - how does the Os prevent that the application accesses kernel memiry then? It can just address the whole address space, can it?

Comment: @PMF that's what paging is for. Each page (4KB) is marked as Supervisor or User - Supervisor pages can't be accessed from userspace applications.